# Devolver las posiciones de una lista

Tags: python

Dispongo del siguiente generador el cuál recorre una lista y si el objeto pasado como parámetro está en la lista lo devuelve y si no se encuentra, devuelve None. Mi duda es como implementar ese mismo generador pero en vez de que me devuelva el objeto en sí me retorne la posición de dicho objeto

```
lista = [0, "hola", 1, "string", 2, "cadena", 3, 4, "5", 45, "879", "Java", 3640, "Django", 1234, "2020", 7]

def list_method(param):
    if param in lista:
        yield param
    else:
        yield None

for i in list_method(5):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Hola Marian, te damos a bienvenida a [es.so] ¿Que debería pasar si el elemento se encuentra varias veces en la lista? Ten en cuenta que no tiene mucho sentido usar un generador y menos iterar sobre e mismo con un for-in cuando siempre genera un solo elemento (None o el índice)...

Comment: Si el elemento se encuentra en la lista, debe devolver todas las posiciones en las que el objeto se encuentre

Comment: Pista: Utiliza Enumerate para encontrar la posición:  
`for posicion, i in enumerate(list_method(5)):
    print(posicion)`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la posición en la que se encuentra el elemento dentro de la lista puedes utilzar `lista.index`:

```
lista = [0, "hola", 1, "string", 2, "cadena", 3, 4, "5", 45, "879", "Java", 3640, "Django", 1234, "2020", 7]

def list_method(param):
    if param in lista:
        yield lista.index(param)
    else:
        yield None

for i in list_method(5):
    print(i)
```

Cabe señalar que en el ejemplo `5`va a retornar `None` puesto que no existe como valor númerico dentro de la lista. Si se pasa `list_method("5")` entonces retorna `8` que es la posición donde se encuentra. El primer elemento es la posición `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Si tal como comentas:

> Si el elemento se encuentra en la lista, debe devolver todas las posiciones en las que el objeto se encuentre

primero necesitas iterar sobre la lista al completo e ir comparando cada item con `param`, si coinciden generas el índice. Para obtener el indice de forma eficiente basta con que uses la función preconstruida  `enumerate`. `if param in lista` solo te devuelve `True` si el elemento existe al menos una vez y `list.index` solo retorna el indice de la primera ocurrencia encontrada o una excepción (`ValueError`) si no existe.

Sería recomendable que la lista fuera pasada también como parámetro en vez de acceder directamente a una variable global.

```
def list_occurrences(param, lista):
    found = False
    for index, item in enumerate(lista):
        if item == param:
            yield index
            found = True
    if not found:
        yield None
```

Ejemplos de ejecución:

```
lista = [0, "hola", 5, "python", 5, "foo", 5, "5"]

for i in list_occurrences(5, lista):
    print(i)
```

> ```
> 2
> 4
> 6
> ```

```
lista = [0, "hola", 5, "python", 5, "foo", 5, "5"]

for i in list_occurrences("bar", lista):
    print(i)
```

> ```
> None
> ```